# how to build a micro processor?

Tags: embedded, microprocessor

I have learnt about 8085 micro processor in my 4th sem of engineering. Now I want to make own 8085 micro processor . My question is how should I start ? What are the requirements and which are the things I should know to do so ?

Comment: What you should know is that building a microprocessor is out of your reach, as it is for anyone in the world.

Comment: Start here: http://www.homebrewcpu.com/

Comment: Write it in Verilog.

Comment: You can build something that will act as your processor, using wired logics or FPGA. This is doable. But what you can't do is make an IC.

Comment: That's illegal! you can't just go and copy Intel's 8085 processor! Make sure you ask them at least ;D  *sarcasm*

Comment: Check out the YouTube playlist by madmaxx called "Lets Build 8-bit Computer"

Comment: To build an 8085 microprocessor would cost hundreds of millions of dollars, maybe more. To build an 8085 based microcomputer would cost less than $500 in parts.

Comment: As someone stated below, try to write or research a cpu build on a FPGA. There are a lot of examples of soft-core CPU's on FPGA's. In this way it's easier to prototype and change things yourself then doing it the hard(-ware) way.

Answer (score 4):

You could get ahold of an FPGA evaluation board and learn VHDL or Verilog.

[Here](http://opencores.org/project,turbo8051) you can find an open-source project to simulate an 8051 core, written in Verilog, and [here](http://opencores.org/project,t51) is a stable 8051 project written in VHDL.

Note the use of the [Wishbone Bus](http://cdn.opencores.org/downloads/wbspec_b4.pdf).

Edit:I wanted to point to two similar projects that used VHDL and Verilog in case you're in the position to choose between them. (They're both popular hardware description languages). Dave Tweed rightly points out that the 8051, though also an Intel 8-bit processor used in controller applications is not that similar to the 8085. [Here's](http://opencores.org/project,cpu8080) an 8080 project (Verilog) that should give a another perspective.

Anyway, the intention is not to point you to an example of your proposed project that has already been completed, but to give you an idea of what is involved so you can see where to go.

Comment: 8051 != 8085. Not even close.

Comment: @DaveTweed Certainly not- see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you're really asking is how to build an 8085-based computer, not how to literally build an 8085 chip.

Unfortunately, that's a difficult prospect, because most of the chips you would need have long been obsolete.

One possibility would be to get your hands on a TRS-80 Model 100 laptop computer, which was based on a CMOS version of the 8085. These are still available at hamfests (electronics flea markets) and on Ebay, etc. There's also plenty of documentation available on their internal construction and how to "hack" them.